# How to convert BigDecimal to recievied digits without separator

Tags: java

Hi I trying recievied the only digtis from BigDecimal. The following examples imaging what i expect

```
1.23 -> 123
123.99 -> 12399
1.345 -> 1345
0.23 -> 23
```

I trying with DecimalFormat but i dont have Idea which pattern is correct.

Comment: value.toString().replace(".", "");

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = bigDecimalValue.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

You can cast it to a numeric type but it is a bit dangerous because big decimal can be a big number and it might not fit in an int.

Comment: but this resolution not will working with case of 0.25 -> 25

Comment: Well if you wan the number value then you can then parse the result. Maybe to BigInteger ;)